# Keep getting error "is not a class or namespace" or "cannot call member function without object"

Tags: c++, class, methods, scope, void

I get this error, so I got this suggestion to try methods... I had an epic fail. This is my code, I don't know what I'm doing wrong, please explain and correct me, I want to learn, not just fix the problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

class datum
{
    public:
    int leto;
    int mesec;
    int dan;
};

class racun
{
    string naslov;
    float cena; // Skupna cena na računu
    int i; // Števec
public:
    datum izdaje; //racuna

   void nastavi_izracunaj_izpisi()
    {

        izdaje.dan = rand() % 30 + 1; //Dan
        izdaje.mesec = rand() % 12 + 1; //Mesec
        izdaje.leto = rand() % 30 + 1985; //Leto
        i = rand() % 100; // Koliko računov smo imeli.
        int produkti;
        produkti = rand() % i + 200; //Koliko produktov smo imeli
        int produkt1[200]; //cena prvega produkta
        int produkt2[200]; //cena drugega produkta
        int a; //števec produktov
        a=0; //ki ga nastavimo na nič
        do
            {
                produkt1[a] = rand() % 200;
                produkt2[a] = rand() % 200;
                a=a+1;
            }while(a!=produkti);
            int b; //kateri produkt bo izpisalo
            b = rand() % 200;
            cout<<"Kupili ste:"<<produkti<<" produktov"<<endl; //izpis za produkte 
        do
            {
                cena=produkt1[b]+produkt2[b];
                i++;
            }while(i!= produkti);
            cout<<"Cena računa brez ddv je: "<<cena<<endl;

            //DDV
            float ddv = 1.12797374897;
            float cena2;
            float cenaddv;
            cena2=cena/ddv;
            cenaddv=cena+cena2;
            cout<<"Cena računa z ddv je: "<<cenaddv<<endl;

    }
};

int main()
{
    racun nekaj;
    nekaj::nastavi_izracunaj_izpisi(); //Nena dela, FAG
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `nekaj::nastavi_izracunaj_izpisi()` should be `nekaj.nastavi_izracunaj_izpisi()` - you're calling a member function on an object.  `::` is used for static member function, with the class name rather than the object name as prefix.

Comment: now my programm just crashes... Why is that? :O

Comment: I don't know - I haven't looked at it that carefully.  It's more useful if you learn how to find out rather than me working it out and telling you - I suggest you start by putting `std::cout` statements throughout the code until you can see exactly which line is crashing (because the output from the prior line's shown, but not the following line).  If you can't work out why it crashes there, then ask us.  Alternatively, use an interactive debugger like gdb or Visual Studio's.

Comment: I'm now looking where my code crashes... If I find anything I'll post here.

Comment: wow, I found the error, not sure why it is happening. It is in this line:
"int produkt1[200]; //cena prvega produkta"
"int produkt2[200]; //cena drugega produkta"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
nekaj::nastavi_izracunaj_izpisi();
// should be
nekaj.nastavi_izracunaj_izpisi();
```

It's the right way to call a method. Or to access a member (as @Ben Voigt said).

```
// Tehre an integer division by 0 on this line
produkti = rand() % i + 200;

// because this line always return 0
i = rand() % 100; // Koliko računov smo imeli.
```

Comment: s/call a method/access a member/

Comment: Euh... It compiled but it crashed your console!?!

Comment: yes, It compiled, then when I run it, it crashed my console (program), as I'm using console app...

Comment: It's because of this:
"int produkt1[200]; //cena prvega produkta", what is wrong whit this line?

Comment: No it's not this line. I strongly suggest you to use a debugger, to place a breakpoint and to run your code line by line. Visual studio express if you are on Windows, Eclipse or Netbeans on a linux distro (or Windows again). See my edit.

Comment: oh, tnx so much... Now everything works, but this:
"do
            {
                produkt1[a] = rand() % 200 +1;
                produkt2[a] = rand() % 200 +1;
                a=a+1;
            }while(a!=produkti);"
for produkt1 I get 0x28f828, why is that?

Comment: I keep getting the same numbers... random function doesn't work :(

Comment: Again, you should use a debugger :) We clearly see that `a` starts to get bigger than 199... At `a = 200`, your program dies because you access memory that may or may not belong to you. As for the random question, read the [doc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/) (srand...) If you still have a bug, your reflex will be to ask it here, but you really **should use a debugger!**